# Pyspark String(having format of timestamp) convert to string

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to convert a string coming as 5/1/21 1:30 (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm)to another string with format as 2021-05-01 01:30:00 (in standard Spark format). Can this be achieved in Pyspark without writing a UDF. If yes then how can we do it, using to_timestamp is giving null values. I know to_timestamp converts to timestampvalue, I was thinking of converting to timestamp and then again to string. Note requirement is convert a string to another string with the above format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is easy. You just have to set the configuration `spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy` to `LEGACY`

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import dateutil.parser



sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

### This is very important setting if you want legacy behaviour
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")

data1 = [["5/1/21 1:30"]]

df1Columns = ["ts"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)

dategiven = "5/1/21 1:30"

date_parsed = dateutil.parser.parse(dategiven)
print("given parser", date_parsed)

new_df = df1.withColumn("converted_ts", F.to_timestamp(F.col("ts"), 'MM/dd/yy HH:mm'))
new_df.show()
```

Output :

```
given parser 2021-05-01 01:30:00
+-----------+-------------------+
|         ts|       converted_ts|
+-----------+-------------------+
|5/1/21 1:30|2021-05-01 01:30:00|
+-----------+-------------------+
```